# Social network architecture decision

Tags: javascript, php, frontend, backend

As I can't orientate freely in the topic of building dynamic sites, it is quite hard to me to google this. So I'll try to explain the problem to you.

I'm developing a simple social network. I've built a basic PHP API represented by the files like "get_profile.php", "add_post.php", etc. with the POST method that is used to pass some data. Then I try to get the data using JS AJAX (php functions return it by JSON), which means I get all the data that I need to show on a page after the page is loaded. That causes decreasing of a page loading speed and I feel like this structure is really wrong.

I hope you'll explain me how to build a proper structure or at least give me some links to read. Thanks.

Comment: A good example of a social network type of site using PHP can be found within this book.  It leverages a PHP framework called Zend2, I would look at how ZF2 solves problems & compare with your own. http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-2-application-development/book

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your architecture right, it sounds ok.

#### Advices

Making your architecture similar to this allows you to deliver [templates](https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more) for the page structure that you then populate with data from your ajax request. This makes your server faster also since it doesn't have to render the HTML also.

Be careful with the amount of requests you make though, if each client makes a lot of them you will have a problem.

Try and break your application into different major pieces and treat each one in turn. This will allow you to separate them into modules later on. This practice is also referred as micro-services architecture.

After you broke them down try and figure user interaction and patterns. This will help you design your database and model in a way in which you can easily optimise for most frequest use-cases.

#### The way of the pros.

You should study how facebook is doing things. They are quite open about it.
For example, the [BigPipe](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/faster-web-page-loading-with-facebook-bigpipe/) method is the fastest I have seen for loading a page.

Also, I think you should read a bit about RESTful applications and SOA type architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the HTML with the (minimum) required data on the server side and load all other necessary data on the client side using AJAX  (as you already do).

In any case, I would profile your application to find the most important bottle necks. Do you parallelize AJAX requests?

Facebook, for example, doesn't populate its HTML with the actual data on the server side, but provides the rough structure, which is later filled using AJAX requests.

[image: Facebook screenshot]